# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I got this error when I try to run flutter app.
The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../helpers/custom_trace.dart';
import '../repository/settings_repository.dart' as settingRepo;
import '../repository/user_repository.dart' as userRepo;

class SplashScreenController extends ControllerMVC with ChangeNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<Map<String, double>> progress = new ValueNotifier(new Map());
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  SplashScreenController() {
    this.scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    // Should define these variables before the app loaded
    progress.value = {"Setting": 0, "User": 0};
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    configureFirebase(firebaseMessaging);
    settingRepo.setting.addListener(() {
      if (settingRepo.setting.value.appName != null && settingRepo.setting.value.appName != '' && settingRepo.setting.value.mainColor != null) {
        progress.value["Setting"] = 41;
        progress?.notifyListeners();
      }
    });
    userRepo.currentUser.addListener(() {
      if (userRepo.currentUser.value.auth != null) {
        progress.value["User"] = 59;
        progress?.notifyListeners();
      }
    });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 20), () {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey?.currentContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(S.of(state.context).verify_your_internet_connection),
      ));
    });
  }

  void configureFirebase(FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging) {
    try {
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: notificationOnMessage,
        onLaunch: notificationOnLaunch,
        onResume: notificationOnResume,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: 'Error Config Firebase'));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: message['data']['id']));
    try {
      if (message['data']['id'] == "orders") {
        settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 1);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    String messageId = await settingRepo.getMessageId();
    try {
      if (messageId != message['google.message_id']) {
        if (message['data']['id'] == "orders") {
          await settingRepo.saveMessageId(message['google.message_id']);
          settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 1);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message['notification']['title'],
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
//      backgroundColor: Theme.of(state.context).backgroundColor,
//      textColor: Theme.of(state.context).hintColor,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

Tried to change to initializeApp();
Didn't Work.
flutter clean 
flutter upgrade 
flutter pub get 
didn't work

[image: Flutter Doctor]

Comment: This is an older configuration syntax, `configure` method was removed already in version 8.0.0. Check out the new one and make changes accordingly, see [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/).

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseMessaging.configure` has been removed since 8.0.0 as mentioned in the [changelog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366142/try-correcting-the-name-to-the-name-of-an-existing-method-or-defining-a-method). What should be used is the [onMessage](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessage.html) Stream to listen for incoming FCM payload.